# Jansson C Librabry for JSON parsing having memory leaks?

Tags: c++, ios, c, memory-leaks, cocos2d-x

I have been trying to integrate the Soomla C++ project in my iOS game for in-app purchase. It has been integrated and works perfectly but upon using the Instruments tool on my mac I keep getting some memory leaks specially in the Jansson library for JSON encoding and decoding.

[image: Screen Shot Intruments]

In one of the cases it gives a memory leak when a malloc is being done and in another case when this same function is being called.

Can anyone help me find out what could be causing the memory leaks and how to solve the issue?

Comment: It relies on how your code calls Jansson APIs. Do you remember to call `json_decref()` correctly?

Comment: Am I explicitly supposed to call json_decref() ? Because I am not directly using the Janasson library, instead I am using Soomla which is using this library. 

Also the memory leak happens at the very start of the application. As soon as I invoke my first call to Soomla. But I guess you are right, I might have to look at how Soomla is calling this library

Comment: You're probably never dereferencing your json data. Sometimes Instruments gives false positives for memory leaks especially when you want the object to remain persistent throughout the lifetime of the application.